# Ant complains about "Cannot run program "cvs"

Tags: java, ant, cvs

Simple question (at least that's my hope) :)

I have a simple ant scritp that checks out files from cvs. It works only if I have CVS_HOME set on Windows path (PATH=c:\cvs), otherwise it returns a error:

**Error**:
build.xml:60: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cvs" (in directory "C:\antTest\cntl"): CreateProcess error=2

- line 60 is the line where I call  task.

**Question**: is there any way to make cvs task find the cvs executable without set it in the windows path?

Comment: How is that supposed to work then? You want ant to guess where CVS bin is located? Ant will not scan your entire computer to find cvs executable.

Comment: Then? Hard code the cvs command in exec task while leave the path to cvs executable a property; declare the property at the beginning of the build file, or pass it from commandline using -Dxxx=xxx. THERE IS ALWAYS A WAY, BUT NOT ALWAYS A GOOD ONE.

Answer (score 1):

not really. if windows can't find it, neither can Ant, unless you give it the absolute path.

Comment: I know ... I think my question was not clear enought! I'm looking for a way to set it at runtime, maybe passing it to script as a property or something. I tried to set cvsrsh attribute pointing to the cvs.exe but it doesn't make any effect.